Is there a Christian denomination that teaches that God cannot heal?
Prompted by a Meta conversation this question asks if there are any Christian denominations which teach that God cannot heal our physical bodies in the here and now.
I am not asking after teachings regarding when, if, or how God may or may not heal.  I am asking if any Christians officially, denominationally teach that God cannot ... that it is impossible for Him.  Not that He "does not" but that He "cannot".

Some believe that miracles were to draw attention to the inauguration of the New Testament (after which inauguration they were no longer required) and that now they have ceased. And some of those would accept that ordinary healing (but not spectacularly) is to be expected (with eldership anointing oil). Are you asking about everyday healing or are you asking about miraculous events which must be classed as 'supernatural' ? (Up-voted +1.)

@NigelJ I am trying to ask something more fundamental than what is along the spectrum of the continuation/cessation debate.  Most hard line cessationists, I think, would admit that God "can" but "doesn't" anymore.  I am wondering if anyone officially teaches that God cannot.

Is this the deist position that inspired Thomas Jefferson to write his miracle free version of the Bible? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_Bible

@Peter Turner - Although at times, Jefferson acted like a Deist, my research concluded that Jefferson wrote a "simplified book of basic principles"  so that the indigenous peoples (Indians) could understand the Principles upon which America was founded (Gospels).  It was not called the "Jefferson Bible" originally.  [Recall that Jefferson included a Christian Seminary in the University of Virginia he founded. When Superintendent of Schools in Wash. D.C. he required the Bible to be placed in them for instruction, as well.]

@raygrant this letter from Thomas Jefferson to John Adams certainly makes him sound like a deist, especially in his denial of the trinity.  https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Jefferson/98-01-02-3446

@ Mike Borden - Yes, that is why I said, at times because there is ambivalence when considering a person's whole life span, not just one year or event or publication.  Some also say Benjamin Franklin was a Deist (God is there but aloof), yet he strongly advised the Constitutional Convention patriots to pray to God for Providential guidance in framing the greatest Constitution in the history of mankind!

@raygrant it's one thing to wiffle waffle on whether or not God will respond to prayer. It's something else to deny the deity of Christ and vicarious atonement.  Some of America's founders may have been born again but not the majority, I think.  At any rate, this is going down a bunny trails:)

I have looked a little bit differently and found a few view points.

God is Omnipotent (contradicts scripture actually)
God is Almighty, but actually limited some (Scripture based)
God is 1 or 2, but is uninvolved (Deism)
God is unable. (you are asking for this one)

I'll stay on topic, and focus on 3 and 4. (but I will have to reference #2 to address the 4th)

God is uninvolved
God "doesn't" heal specifically is found within "Christian Deism". (This is distinct from the "does not... because..." view you were avoiding)
Here are two of them: "Church of the Modern Deist" (moderndeist.org) and "The World Union of Deists" (deism.com)
Deism holds that God does not interfere with creation anymore, allowing natural laws and stuff to continue. (It also denies the Trinity, Denies the divinity of Christ, etc...)
As such, it is difficult to call them "Christians", they believe in a "supreme being". Unlike The Father, the deist god is more like a clockmaker, who wound up the universe and let it go.
It is of course heresy to most christian denominations because it absolutely strips the faith of all miracles, supernatural events and causes (other then creation) and it involves basically "being saved because your a good person" (saved through works, because there is no supernatural or spiritual salvation)

God cannot...
According to the Bible:

With God all things are possible (Mt. 19:26, but this is about salvation)
God cannot lie (Heb. 6:18, Titus 1:2, John 14:6)
God cannot be tempted by evil (Js. 1:12)
God cannot deny Himself (2 Tim. 2:13)
God cannot not love. (1 John 4:16)

So... there are limits, but the teaching that God cannot affect the physical world. But similarly I've not seen any christian denomination that claims "miracles" or "healing" are things that God cannot do.
All miracles are a matter of faith, as it is pointed out in Mark 6:4-13, he was not able to work miracles around those who had no faith in Him.

There is no "faith" that claims God cannot perform miracles through faith. The closest I've found are "Christian" churches that deny all supernatural, divine, and spiritual realities.

@ Wyrsa - Additionally, "God cannot write a scientific article in a Journal for "peer review"!

@raygrant: I don't know. If a paper appeared with untracable origin giving the laws of physics as second order differential equations, including the ones we haven't solved yet, that could be reviewed and published.

@ Joshua - Thanks for your response. Trueness, it could be reviewed and published, but not by a Peer because God has no equal! He alone is God eternal.

Good answer! I should mention that when Christian theologians call God "omnipotent" they do not mean to say that he does not have the limitations you mention. (Note that "omnipotent" is just the Latin equivalent of the Germanic word "almighty".) What we mean is that those limitations are not extrinsic to God, nor are they due to some lack of power, but rather due to his character. For example, when we say God cannot lie, we don't mean that he might desire to lie but find himself unable (like Jim Carey in Liar, Liar), but rather that in his character he will never even have that desire.

@DarkMalthorp You are fun to have around the site. I liked the recent answers I saw from you as well. Also the robo rider as an icon is just so good.

Oh, thank you! <3

@raygrant  Of course, God could write a peerless review - of anything!

I can find no Christian denomination that officially states that God does not do miracles, healing or otherwise, in present day. But you can find those that adhere to cessationism in Baptist and Reformed churches. Even they wouldn't say God can't.
There are some denominations that are friendly to treating even Biblical miracles as metaphor rather than event (like Bishop Spong of ECA).
Wikedia entry on cessationism v. continuationism

I had hoped, in the question, to draw a distinction between "does not" and "can not", excluding the former.  I have made an edit for clarity and I am sorry if that negatively affects your answer.

"God can't" won't fly in cessationism, but it may fly in liberal interpretation that denies all miracles.
